# function valued 1 on an open set and 0 on another

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $X,Y \subset M$ be closed subsets of a metric space $M$. Assume that $\inf_{x\in X,y\in Y} d(x, y) > 1$. Prove that there exists a 1-Lipschitz function on $M$ which is equal to 1 on $X$ and 0 on $Y$.

Any hints on where to start?

Comment: I don't think differential geometry is a good tag. The question isn't about it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Think about functions like this:

$$f(x) = \frac{{\rm dist}(x,Y)}{{\rm dist}(x,X)+{\rm dist}(x,Y)},$$

where $\displaystyle {\rm dist}(x,A) = \inf_{y\in A} d(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a go at it

Comment: I have no idea how to show that it is 1-lipschitz. Is there a trick or just calculations and inserting $x-x+y-y$ at the right moment?

Answer (score 0):

For $x \in X$, draw $$
D_x := \{p \in M:\; d(p,x) \leq 1\},
$$ and define $$
D := \bigcup_{x \in X} D_x
$$ By assumption, $D \cap Y =\varnothing$. Also, define $$
g_x(z) :=\begin{cases} d(z,x),\quad z \in D_x \\ 1,\quad \rm{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$ Define $$
f(z) := \inf_{x \in X} g_x(z)
$$ Notice $f(y) =1$ for all $y \in Y$.

Consider any two points $u,v \in M$. If $d(u,v) >1$ then we are done. Thus assume $d(u,v) \leq 1$.

Suppose that $u,v \in D$.
Let $x_u$, $x_v$ be resp. the center of cone whose shape $f(u),f(v)$ were taken. That is to say, $$
d(x_u,u) =f(u),\quad d(x_v,v) =f(v).
$$ And we have, by construction, $$
d(x_u,u) <d(x_v,u),\quad d(x_v,v) <d(x_u,v)
$$ Since $\Delta x_u uv$ and $\Delta x_v uv$ both satisfy triangle inequality (as should any metric do), we can draw corresponding quadrilateral $x_u x_v vu$ on the normal Euclidean plane. By [A relation between sides of quadrilateral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399299/a-relation-between-sides-of-quadrilateral/2399305?noredirect=1#comment4950847_2399305) which I just asked, $$
|f(v)-f(u)| =|d(x_u,u) -d(x_v,v)| \leq d(u,v).
$$

Then (wlog) consider $u \in D$ but $v \in M-D$, and find $x_u$ the center of the cone on which $f(u)$ is taken. Notice (by assumption) $$
d(x_u,u) \leq 1 \leq d(x_u,v)
$$ Thus, similarly, $$
|f(v) -f(u)| =1 -f(u) =1 -d(x_u,u)
\leq d(x_u,v) -d(x_u,u) =|d(x_u,v) -d(x_u,u)| \leq d(u,v).
$$ ($d(x_u,v) >1$ otherwise $v \in D$. Then triangle inequality is used.)

The case $u,v \in M-D$ is trivial, since $|f(v) -f(u)| =|1-1| =0 \leq |u-v|$.

Comment: Not quite sure about this... Why is $1-f(u) = d(v,u)$? And in the second set of inequalities, why is $\vert f(u)-f(w)\vert \leq d(u,w)$? If $d(u,w)<1$, ok, but that is not the case. And I don't agree that $\vert f(w)-f(v)\vert \leq 0$

Comment: @tomak Please see my new answer!