# A relation between sides of quadrilateral

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, quadrilateral, geometric-inequalities

Suppose $ABCD$ a quadrilateral (in Euclidean geometry), with $$
\overline{AD} \leq \overline{AC},\\
\overline{BC} \leq \overline{BD}.
$$ Then show that $$
|\overline{AD} - \overline{BC}| \leq \overline{AB}.
$$ 
(I will soon post a proof of mine which I am not sure whether it's completely rigorous. This is intended as a lemma for my proof of [Existence of an 1-Lipschitz function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394160/function-valued-1-on-an-open-set-and-0-on-another).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$-AB<AD-BC<AB.$$
Indeed, 
$$AD+AB>BD>BC$$ and we got a left inequality and
$$AB+BC>AC>AD$$ and we got a right inequality.

Done!

Comment: Oh .... hmmm.... urghhhh.... >< I was thinking of this for several hours, and you were even faster than me completing typing my proof.

Comment: @Aminopterin The triangle inequality forever!

Answer (score 0):

Now, draw a circle $C_A$ with center $A$, radius $\overline{AD}$, and draw a circle $C_B$ with center $B$, radius $\overline{BC}$.

Suppose $C_A,C_B$ intersect at one or two points, let any of the two points be $E$. Then $$
|\overline{AD}-\overline{BC}|
=|\overline{AE}-\overline{BE}|
\leq \overline{AB}
$$ because of property of $\Delta ABE$.

Suppose $C_A,C_B$ do not intersect. Then $C_A$ and $\overline{AB}$ must intersect; call it $E$. Similarly let $C_A$ and $\overline{AB}$ intersect at $F$. So, $$
|\overline{AD}-\overline{BC}|
=|\overline{AE}-\overline{BF}|
\leq |\overline{AB}-0|.
$$